# Get app's storage path without context

Tags: android, android-service

I have a background service which activates `BroadcastReceiver` class when it receives some content. I want to save that to the app's path in external dir, which is returned by calling `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` (/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.app/). However, since this happens in the background, I have no context and so I cannot get that path. I absolutely do not wish to hard code the path and want the data to get deleted when the app is uninstalled. Any other way in which I can get that complete path?

Comment: "However, since this happens in the background, I have no context" -- a `Context` is passed in as a parameter to `onReceive()`. And, since your disk I/O should be delegated to a `Service` (probably an `IntentService` to use its background thread)., a `Service` is also a `Context`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Service itself is a context http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html you can use.

```
this.getExternalFilesDir()
```

on the service.

Comment: Missed that big point. Service does have a context and it is passed on to the `onReceive()` method in `BroadcastReceiver` class, as CommonsWare mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Service does not need a context, because Service *IS* a Context.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Android 6 & prior to forced scoped storage, the following would work with Android 5.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

This answer no longer works on Android 11 and in 2020.

Comment: That is not the same as **getExternalFilesDir**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Is there a reason not to use it even though it is different?

Comment: @Jeremiah I believe it is a different directory, may not be mounted, and is shared across all applications.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment

Comment: using this directory requires runtime permissions wheras the the app's storage path does not

Comment: @SameerJJ in 2015, we didn't want runtime permissions

Answer (score 0):

You do not need context if you know the address of the file you want to read.

```
String getKey(String filename) throws IOException {
    // Read from file
    String myStringFromFile= "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        myStringFromFile+= line;
    }
    br.close();
    return myStringFromFile;
}
```

where fileName is the path.

```
String privatePem = "/sdcard/someFolder/someFile.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a static field in a static class about the external folder path, and then initialize it in your application class.

For instance:

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IOUtils.cacheFolder = IOUtils.getCacheDir(this);
    }
}

public class IOUtils {
    public static File cacheFolder;
    /**
    * Return the folder for cache files.
    */
   public static File getCacheDir(Context context) {
       File cache = context.getExternalCacheDir();
       if (cache == null)
           cache = context.getCacheDir();
       return cache;
   }
}
```

A little ugly but works. You can use **IOUtils.cacheFolder** in your background thread without context. Caching a file reference in static field, won't lead to any memory issue.